# Cannot use ant to compile 1.7 java project

Tags: java, ant, java-7

I've some java project (liferay portlet) that uses ant for build.

I've the following jdk:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_67
$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
```

Although, When I try to `ant compile` the source code - from command line- (where I switch on Strings, a feature introduced in jdk1.7), I got the following:

```
Cannot switch on a value of type String. Only convertible int values or enum constants are permitted
```

Here's the snippet from my build.xml:

```
<javac
                 source="1.7"
                 target="1.7"
                 classpathref="${javac.classpathref}"
                 compiler="${javac.compiler}"
                 debug="${javac.debug}"
                 deprecation="${javac.deprecation}"
                 destdir="${javac.destdir}"
                 encoding="${javac.encoding}"
                 includeAntRuntime="false"
                 nowarn="${javac.nowarn}"
                 srcdir="${javac.srcdir}"
          />
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What's the value you have for JAVA_HOME?

Comment: points to jdk1.7 directory `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/`

Comment: check also ANT_OPTS; and, just in case, double check that the value of ${javac.compiler} actually points to your jdk1.7

Comment: `javac.compiler` points to jdk1.7, I knew that by running `ant & ps aux| grep [j]ava` and made sure that, the jdk1.7 is being executed. Also `ANT_OPTS` is empty

Comment: is there maybe some other java/javac installation on the path?

Comment: I've another installation `jdk1.8`, but `JAVA_HOME` refers to 1.7. Even if, it should work in jdk1.8 too.